# What is the largest concert performed?

Tags: history, live-music

What and when is the largest concert performed in terms of *paying* attendees?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know whether this still stands, but the Guiness Book of World Records at some point listed a-Ha's performance at the 1991 Rock in Rio concert as the record holder with [198,000 paid attendance](http://rockinrio.com/usa/great-artists-make-history-a-ha/).

Answer (score 4):

Copacabana (Rio de Janeiro), Rio de Janeiro, New Year's Eve 1994 featuring Rod Stewart with an attendance of 3.5 million.

Source ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_concerts),[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copacabana,_Rio_de_Janeiro#Notable_events))

Comment: a) already mentioned & b) *paying* attendees is the question. That aside, I bet it was difficult to hear anything from the back :P

Comment: @Tetsujin you must have missed the time showing on rite side of profile picture of answered person. And when i submitted the answer, this example was not there. Maybe few seconds early or late.

Comment: ah, yes - for me, I saw one this morning, the other [yours] this evening. I didn't check the timestamps, tbh.